# How to arrive to this formula $A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, triangles, area

Heron's formula for area of any tinangles
$$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\tag1$$

Where $a,b$ and $c$ are the sides of the triangle. $s$ is the semi-perimeter of the triangle.

$$s={a+b+c\over 2}$$

**How did they derive this formula $(1)$?**